# Class 'Foo' not found laravel 3 task

Tags: laravel, laravel-3

Error: `Class 'Ibooks_Controller' not found in/Users/winas/workspace/media_admin/media_books/application/tasks/sample.php`

Class that produces error: `class Sample_Task extends Ibooks_Controller`

Ibooks_Controller path: `/Users/winas/workspace/media_admin/media_books/application/controllers/ibooks.php`

How can I properly call the function that Ibooks_controller have inside of sample.php

Answer (score 1):

you can't extend a Controller when making a Task. And more importantly, it would be something really bad to do.
I don't know what it is that you're trying to do, but if you want to access any data, you should use models and/or libraries for that.

Besides that, a short explanation on why the class is not found.
Laravel only autoloads files/classes that are in the "models" and "libraries" directories. (There might be more)
Controllers are only loaded when a Route request that controller to be loaded. And will only then search for which controller to load.

If you need to load classes that are not in one of the standard auto-loaded classes, you can load it using the Laravel Autoloader class:
http://three.laravel.com/docs/loading